# Erro de Áudio na Máquina Virtual do Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms, visual-studio-2017

Estou estudando um tutorial de Xamarin, e estou tentando rodar cada passo dele em duas máquinas diferentes, só que numa delas o emulador fecha com o seguinte erro:

> Device error: audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'
>   qemu-system-i386.exe: warning: opening audio input failed
>   audio: Failed to create voice `adc'
>   glTexImage2D: got err pre :( 0x505 internal 0x1908 format 0x1908 type 0x1401

[image: Screenshot Android Device Manager]

Apesar de entender que este problema possa ser apenas desta máquina (já que na outra o app funciona), uma busca pelo erro mostrou que outras pessoas já passaram por isso, mas as soluções dadas não foram suficientes no meu caso.

Existe alguma maneira de circunvir essa situação?